# I Want to Assign Multiple Roles to a single user

Tags: php, wordpress

I've found below two lines to be inserted somewhere in our theme to get the job done:

```
$addMemberToGroup = new WP_User($required_id);
$addMemberToGroup->add_role( $role );
```

But I dont know where to place these lines.
Does anybody know where exactly to put those?

Answer (score 0):

On which action you want to assign user role, generally custom code need to put in theme's function.php file (if child theme then put in child theme's function.php file) but it all depends on your requirement.

Answer (score 0):

```
$addMemberToGroup = new WP_User($required_id);
$addMemberToGroup->add_role( $role );
```

Put these lines to your theme functions.php

Create a function:

```
function add_new_role_to_user( $role ) {
   $addMemberToGroup = new WP_User($required_id);
   $addMemberToGroup->add_role( $role );
}
```

After that you need to hook this function

```
add_action( 'admin_init', 'add_new_role_to_user' );
```